# setContentView не принимает аргумент, хотя он есть

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В файле EditObjectActivity написан следующий код:

```
package com.example.litstorage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class EditObjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_object); //проблема здесь
    }
}
```

Файл activity_edit_object существует, однако функция отказывается принимать этот аргумент, среда предлагает создать файл с таким же названием.

[image: файл существует]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Проверьте, что, создавая файл, не использовали случайно русские буквы

Comment: Название файла было создано автоматически при создании EditObjectActivity, все написано латинскими буквами

Comment: Физически-то он существует, но проиндексирован ли он а ресурсах? Попробуйте пересобрать проект

Comment: Не видно импорта R класса.

Comment: Возможно, Вы перенесли активность из другого проекта (см. package).